# How do I pass driver information from one method to other

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am new to selenium.
Please help with my query.
I have one method urlload in which I am loading a particular URL.
Suppose I am creating another method in same class or another class, I am unable to read webElements of webpage loaded in urlload method.
Please help.

```
public class loading {
    public static void urlload() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Options);
        String baseurl = "http://www.google.com/";
        System.out.println(baseurl);
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using constructor you can pass driver reference.

//constructor

`public Classname(WebDriver driver)
{
this.driver = driver;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new, try this. Its not about selenium but the programming language.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = setUp();
        driver = test(driver);
        tearDown(driver);
    }
public static WebDriver setUp() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseurl = "http://www.google.com/";
    System.out.println(baseurl);
    driver.get(baseurl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}

public static WebDriver test(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
    return driver;
}

public static void tearDown(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}
}
```